# Cannot read property 'getContext' of null at window.onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, nullreferenceexception, canvasjs

```
window.onload = function() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('chart-area').getContext('2d');
    window.myDoughnut = new Chart(ctx, config);
};
```

When window load that time may chart function is not working and error was accrued "can't read property **"getcontext"** of null.

Comment: At the time the code runs, `document.getElementById('chart-area')` is null / isn't finding anything.  Do you have the correct `id` or are you creating the id after your code runs?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this one :

```
document.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(document.readyState == "complete") {

        //document is ready . Do you stuff here
    }
}
```

source : [DOM - readyState](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState)